# Write a program with infinite expected output

Tags: code-golf, random

Write a program that halts producing a random finite numerical output with probability 1. The [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of the outputs of the program must be infinite.

For [physical limits](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/), you can assume your language and related functions use infinite precision numbers. E.g. for languages with random function providing range \$[0,1)\$, it returns a real in \$[0,1)\$. (Anyway I need to choose from `1/rnd` and `while(rnd)print(1)`)

Inspired by [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox).

Shortest code wins. Would be quite small for lots of language though.

---

There are two easy-seen ways to do this, both are accepted given the question: (in Javascript)

```
_=>1/Math.random() // ∫₀¹1/xdx=∞
_=>{c='1';while(Math.random()<.5)c+='1';return c} // Not golfed to easier get understood for other language user, at least I try to
    // 1/2+11/4+111/8+1111/16+...=∞
```

Comment: The `1/random()` answers don't have an infinite expected value since they are limited by the precision of the rng  (i.e. that fraction has a finite maximum possible value)

Comment: @Leo Default assumes infinity precision right?

Comment: So do we take into account numerical issues or not? If yes, any data type will have a maximum value, so any answer would be invalid, I think. The usual approach is for the answers to be able to assume no data-type limitations

Comment: @Leo not only that, `random()` can output zero which would cause the program to give invalid output

Comment: This question is good, but currently is not well defined. Since most random libraries are just pseudo-random ones, and probably rely on the current timestamp for a seed, should we assume that the program is run at a random time?

Comment: Is it acceptable if the output \$X\$ takes arbitrarily large positive and negative values often enough, such that \$E[X]\$ is undefined and \$E[|X|]=\infty\$? That would be the case e.g. with a [Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) random variable.

Comment: @RobinRyder I don't think so. If some lang have easier tan than 1/, then maybe no E(X) inf E(|X|) shorter though

Comment: @Trebor Such issue should(guess|suggest) be on meta

Comment: Since you haven't addressed my comment (and others), I am voting to close as unclear. Also, what does "random" mean here? Can a constant (infinite) output be considered random?

Comment: @LuisMendo https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/ How `Can a constant (infinite) output be considered random? `

Comment: Because a constant value is a particular case of a random distribution. If you want to rule that out you need to say it explicitly in the challenge text (and notify answers that currently do that so they can be fixed)

Comment: I am voting to reopen now that it has been clarified that the output must be finite, and that we can assume infinite precision.

Comment: Technically your integral justification for `1/random()` is wrong, because the generalized integral diverges: ln(0) does not exist

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 9 bytes

```r
rf(1,1,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyhNw1AHCDX//wcA)

Outputs a realization of the \$F(1,1)\$ distribution. The [\$F(d_1,d_2)\$-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) has infinite mean for \$d_2 \leq 2\$.

One way of defining the \$F(1,1)\$ distribution is as follows: let \$X_1,X_2\$ be independent \$\mathcal N(0,1)\$ random variables. Then \$\frac{X_1^2}{X_2^2}\sim F(1,1)\$.

Using the \$F\$ distribution comes out 1 byte shorter than the 2 more obvious solutions `1/runif(1)` and `rcauchy(1)`.

The plot below shows the evolution of the sample mean, for sample size ranging from 1 to 1e6; you can see that it diverges.

[image]

---

Alternate solution for the same byte count:

```r
rt(1,1)^2
```

which outputs the square of a realization of Student's distribution \$t(1)\$. It has infinite expected value, since the \$t(1)\$ distribution has infinite variance. The square is needed to guarantee that the output is positive; without it, the expected value is undefined, since the realizations are often enough arbitrarily large positive or negative numbers.

Comment: Really nice!  I think we were typing-in our answers at the same time, so I'm glad they came out with the same bytes (although I think yours is better...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I was happy it worked with `rf`, as we never get to use that function usually!

Comment: Hmmm why does the $F(1,1)$ sample means have such strange jagged patterns in the graph?

Comment: @BenjaminWang That is what always occurs for the sample mean of independent and identically distributed random variables with infinite expected value. Intuitively: very occasionally, we obtain a huge realization \$X_i\$, which massively pushes the sample mean up. If the next realizations \$X_{i+1},X_{i+2},\ldots\$ are smaller, the sample mean will slowly decrease as the weight of \$X_i\$ decreases, until it jumps up the next time a huge realization occurs.

Comment: @BenjaminWang On the other hand, if the expected value is *finite*, then the sample mean converges to it by the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) (see plot at the link).

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
1ḤXḂ$¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w4Y4lEQ93NKkc2v//cPvDnS0qhkAWAA)

-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan

50% chance to output 1, 50% chance to output double this value. -2 bytes using a while loop inspired by Aaron Miller's answer.

### Explanation

```
1
     ¿  While
  ..$
  X     Random integer from 1 to (current value)
   Ḃ    % 2 (this ensures 50% chance no matter how large the current value is - except if it's 1)
 Ḥ      Double the current value
```

Unfortunately, Jelly doesn't have a "random decimal from 0 to 1" built-in, otherwise this could be `<random><reciprocal>`.

### Proof of validity

The probability to output \$2^x\$ is \$2^{-x-1}\$ for all \$x\in\mathbb{Z}^+\$. Therefore, the expected output is \$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 2^n\cdot 2^{-n-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac12\rightarrow\infty\$

Comment: I'd suggest golfing to `2ḤX’$¿`, but that seems to rapidly snowball out of control whenever it gets past 4...

Comment: `1ḤXḂ$¿` or `2ḤXḂ$¿` are the same thing just without \$x=0\$.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah, clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 5 bytes

```
?+`
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3147gQtIAQA) Explanation:

```
?+`
```

Loop a random number of times with an exponential distribution...

```
1
```

Double the length. (Actually you get `2ⁿ-1`, but that's still enough to diverge to infinity.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
from random import*
print(1/random())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fnpGZk6oQUlSaaqWQWpGarKGkpPQ/rSg/V6EoMS8FSGXmFuQXlWhxFRRl5pVoGOpDhDU0Nf8DVWr@BwA)

I had a slightly cool solution but now this is just the trivial solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s><sup>6</sup></s> <s><sup>7</sup></s> 3 bytes

*Thanks to @hyper-neutrino for helping me to understand what expected output is.*

*Thanks to @Lyxal for porting a different answer than I did for -4 bytes.*

```
∆ṘĖ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%86%E1%B9%98%C4%96&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
∆Ṙ   # Random float in range [0.0, 1.0)
  Ė  # Reciprocal
     # Implicit output
```

Comment: [here's a 3 byte solution that ports the python answer](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%86%E1%B9%98%C4%96&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 4):

## [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 29 bytes

*Edit: +9 bytes to fix issue spotted by [@RossMillikan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12480/ross-millikan).*

```
1::=.10
10::=~1
.0::=~0
::=
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/39DKylbP0IDL0ADIqDPk0gPTBlxAksuQ6/9/AA) *The TIO interpreter requires a trailing newline, and outputs each digit on a different line, which is not required. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/thue) is an interpreter without these restrictions.*

Outputs in binary ([meta link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5367/31957)). Each step has a 50% chance to double the binary integer, or to start outputting it. The proven formula from other answers.

Comment: I don't think this is acceptable.  It sounds like the chance of $n\ 1$s being output decreases as $2^{-n}$.  In that case the expected value converges.  Absent a startup transient it is just $2$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>169</s> <s>119</s> 118 bytes

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
int main(){std::mt19937 p((uint64_t)new int);std::string s="1";while(p()%2)s+=s;std::cout<<s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCsIwEADvviJUhISgUhWlTepXRLehXWjX4G7oQXx7DHobZgZi3A4AOa@RYEp98A8U3rP0YO1uvK6QRM13JG3eRbbtLHXTHC8qap1KO59uYigsqrBxv4PlhTQo7qq6csuIU9BRm83BsO34v8AziffsPjl/AQ)

This solution is directly derived [from the linked paradox in the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox). The output string is composed of `1` digits so technically it can be interpreted as a number.

The random number generator is seeded with the address of a heap variable. The address changes each time the program is run.

> Another option is to use the address of a newly allocated heap variable:
> `mt19937 rng((uint64_t) new char);` [(source)](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/61675)

Comment: Suggest `(long)&p` instead of `(uint64_t)new int`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
/1OZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X9/QP@r/fwA)

```
/1   # 1 divided by
OZ   # Random float between 0 and 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 24 bytes

```bash
echo 32767/$RANDOM|bc -l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqGpUP0/NTkjX8HYyNzMXF8lyNHPxd@3JilZQTfnfy0XV9p/AA)

Prints a random number between \$1\$ and \$\infty\$.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
1Ｗ‽²↑ＫＡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJUEnTmqs8IzMnVUEjKDEvJT9Xw0hTUwEiaxVaoKMQkJqa7ZiTo6Gpaf3//3/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
1
```

Print `1`.

```
Ｗ‽²
```

Repeat a random number of times with an exponential distribution...

```
↑ＫＡ
```

... duplicate the output.

Comment: 52 bytes? More like 7 bytes.

Comment: @Lyxal Yeah, I normally remember to paste the succinct byte count at the same time as I paste the succinct code over the verbose code but I only got four hours of sleep last night :-(

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 9 bytes

```r
1/rexp(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/31C/KLWiQMNQ8/9/AA)

`rexp(1)` - a single random sample from an exponential distribution with a (default) rate parameter of 1 - is the shortest [R](https://www.r-project.org/) random function call with a nonzero probability density at zero (there are other shorter random functions [`rt` and `rf`], but unfortunately they each lack default values for required parameters, so the function calls are no shorter*).

*Edit: no shorter, but both can be made just-as-short: see [Robin Ryder's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224844/95126)

Comment: For the second solution, you can use the fact that `1/0=Inf` with e.g. `1/rpois(1,1)` (12 bytes), which sometimes outputs `Inf`.

Comment: @RobinRyder - Thanks - you're right, of course (even though I was trying to find a way to use a different approach to the R built-in random distributions).  Anyway, it looks like both of these approaches are now outlawed by the new 'finite numerical output' rule...

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
1r/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/37BI//9/AA)

This produces the output 1/*x*, where *x* is uniformly distributed on  the interval (0,1). This has [infinite mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Inverse_uniform_distribution).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
from time import*
print(time())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehJDM3VSEztyC/qESLq6AoM69EAySkoan5/z8A)

The Python 3 `random` library uses the current time for a seed. Therefore, it is necessary to specify the random distribution of time that the program is run, to ensure that the simple `1/random()` is valid. Depending on the yet-to-come specification, my answer may or may not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
2?.#*@#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/38heT1nLQfn/fwA)

This is basically just the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox). Every time the pointer reaches the `?` and goes either left or right, it has a 1/2 chance of doubling the top of the stack and a 1/2 chance of just outputting the top of the stack and halting.

Explanation of the code:

```
2?.#*@#

2        Push 2 onto the stack.
 ?       Change the direction of the pointer to a random direction:
2   *      If left, double the top of the stack.
  .  @     If right, output the top of the stack and halt.
 ?         If up/down, the pointer returns to the ?.
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 5 bytes

```
÷1-?0
```

The program generates a random number from the range [0; 1), then substracts it from 1 to get the range (0; 1], and takes the reciprocal, so we get a number from the range [1; +∞).

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 3 bytes

```
1nx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3zCv4v9/AA)

Has an infinite expected value, due to diverging more quickly than exponentially more unlikely repunits.
Will nevertheless always terminate when it empties its own stack, when the random trampoline takes more left turns than right turns.

Answer (score 0):

## [Random Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 5 bytes

```
+[?.]
```

Throw a D256 until you throw a 0

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0rMS8nP1U0qSszMSytNzv7/XzvaXi/2/38A)